# Will people be interested in the collaboration that can have the last author?

Tags: publications, supervision, collaboration, research-topic

As a just graduated PhD, I would like to work with other people. But I am a nobody in my field. I am thinking that people will be interested in working with me if I do a postdoc with them or become a visiting scholar. I think that is because that the PI and postdoc both have interest in some topic. I take that as a Win-win. The postdoc can get paid and more important get some direction and advice, and the PI can get his idea be implemented. Both of them have the same goal, they want to do successful research and have some good publication.

However, due to personal reasons, I will not be able to do a postdoc for a long time. I was wondering if I still can work with some people, like a remote postdoc, but the difference is that they do not theoretically hire me. I can have some direction, advice froom them, and they can have their idea be implemented, and both of us want to have sccessful research and discovery or contribution and have some good publication.

Am I too naive about this idea? Or is it possible? How do you get to know the people to collaborate with? What will you say to them when you first meet? Like tell them that I can work together and have some scheduled meeting, and ask them for advice and direction, if every going well they can be last author for the publication?

Comment: Cold emailing people will be difficult, given that they do not know whether you will run off with an idea.   Your best strategy is use your connections, e.g., supervisor(s), or class mates.

Comment: That make sense. Like ask you supervisor or class mates to recommend or introduct some people to work with?

Comment: Don't offer to work for free. It's immoral and undermines your colleagues.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I mean collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, you suggestion to work for somebody and trade their support for an authorship is very wrong. Authorship is something that should not be traded, it has to be earned. And how would you say anything definite about an author list or the author order without any work done, any results, let alone an idea or a concept of what is to be published? So no, I would expect your offer not to be taken into consideration by respectable researchers.

Comment: Thank for you answe. I can see  that you are person with great integrity. However, I may not make myself very clear. Definitely, I won't give somebody a author when he does nothing. I mean of course he has some contribution. The reason why i want to work with these experienced people is that I hope that i can get some advice and direction. But when you purpose a collaboration, you want the let the person know the role I and they will play in that project. So they can give their support and contribution. But of course things change. The final author order depend on their contribution.

Comment: If they did less than what they should do or they did more than they do, I will try to tell them in time. Like either they accept authorship order change or they change their investment to the project. So that I and they will adjust the investment and expectation to the project. Everyone understand what their role in the project. For my experience, if we only discuss the authorship when we are going to submit the paper, there is high risk that people will have argument at that time. I also wonder what you do and how you deal with this problem, it is very welcomed to discuss. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you seem naive about this. People will want to collaborate if they are interested in, and have some skills/background in, you topic. There are, of course, people only interested in citation counts, but those are not the people you want to collaborate with.

Collaboration is a sharing of skills and ideas. Focus on that. If you have some skills and ideas then search for others who seem to be similarly inclined (reading their papers, meeting them at conferences) and start to share ideas. Perhaps something will come from it.

In some specialized fields there are conference where people come together and one can meet presenters, but also just chat up other attendees and see if there is common interest.

But, if people want to "collaborate" just to get authorship, then they are probably the people you don't actually want to work with as the chances of producing something meaningful seems pretty small. Focus on the research, on the ideas. Let the rest follow naturally.

---

I'm guessing that "last authorship" means primary authorship in your field.